# Using T-SQL to execute SSIS package does not return any result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a simple SSIS package that uses C# to generate an Excel file and put it to assigned location.

Package works fine in design mode.

Package been deployed successfully:

[image]

However when I try to execute it from SSMS - then then its only displays `@execution_id`.

```
DECLARE @execution_id BIGINT

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
        @package_name=N'ExcessCopy1.dtsx',
        @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT,
        @folder_name=N'MonthlyReports',
        @project_name=N'MonthlyReports',
        @use32bitruntime=False,
        @reference_id=Null

SELECT @execution_id

DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
        @execution_id,
        @object_type=50,
        @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL',
        @parameter_value=@var0

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution]  @execution_id
GO
```

[image]

If I comment out `SELECT @execution_id`, then I get

> Command completed successfully

However it does not deliver file to assigned location.

[image]

What can be the problem and how can I troubleshoot this issue?

I can see the package under Integrational Service Catalog. 
But I was unable to find this package in SSISBD:

[image]

I was able to see what is the error:

[image]

Comment: What do mean you "nothing". So you don't even get any informational messages?

Comment: Question updated. Thanks

Comment: So, what else are you expecting to happen? The fact that you get an execution ID suggests that the package did indeed start.

Comment: Package supposed to create excel file and put it in assigned location. However, if I execute it from SSMS it doesn't happen. Package works fine in design mode.

Comment: Have you checked the execution logs in SSISDB? That would be where I would start. As you're interacting with a file system as well I ***assume*** you, or your network administrator, has configured your SQL Server for double hop kerboros authentication too, right?

Comment: The last image you posted has the error. You're missing the ACE driver on the sql server box.

Comment: And if it's not just the missing ACE driver, then it will probably be a permissions issue. These are by far the most common problems with SSIS packages working in design/development, but not in production.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040489/the-requested-ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-is-not-registered-if-the)

Answer (score 2):

> What can be the problem

The most likely explanation is that the package puts the file in a place you don't expect because it is now executing on the server and not your local box. Almost equally likely is that the package is encountering an error that it is not passing back to the SSMS window.

> and how can I troubleshoot this issue?

If the package is in SSISDB, you can right click on it and look at the "All Executions" report to verify that the package did execute, and then drill down into the "All Messages" for that execution to see what happened.

Comment: Thanks. The package is not in SSISDB. Is any way I can place it there? So I can troubleshoot?

Comment: Hmm, how are you sure of this?   It seems unlikely that you'd be able to execute the package with `[SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution]` unless the package were in SSISDB.   If it's not in SSISDB, where is it?  In fact, according to the first image in your question, it IS in SSISDB.   Go to the screen you snipped that image from, and right click on the package.  (the line you have circled in the image)

Comment: Your package is definitely in SSISDB, based on your images and SQL @Oleg. If it isn't, then all the information we have isn't relevant to your problem, as they're all SSISDB related.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks. I am not good in SSIS, just starting to implement it for my work. But I am able to see package under `Integrational Service Catalog`, but unable to find it in SSISDB where all databases are. I updated with picture.

Comment: @Oleg don't look there.  In my previous comment, I told you *exactly* what to do in the last sentence.  Right-click on the line you have circled in your first image.   Then go to the "All Executions" report, and drill into "All Messages" for the execution that occurred when you ran your script.

Comment: @Tab. Thank you for your help. I found the error. It says that ACE OLEDB 12.0 driver is missing. I searched the error, and tried to install all those drivers. But unfortunately the error remains.

Comment: What versions of Visual Studio and SQL Server are you using?   This could be because you are not using matching versions.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Server is missing the ACE OLEDB 12.0 driver. You can get it here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

If you need both 64-bit and 32-bit versions installed for some reason, you can install the 64-bit from the link above, but it won't let you also install the 32-bit version, so you can use an older version of the 32-bit driver, which can coexist with the 64-bit one. You can get that one here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

Comment: Thank you. I have this error for a while. And no matter what drivers I install - the problem remains.

Comment: You installed them on the SQL server where the package is running, right?

Comment: Yes. I have dev and production environment. My project is on dev and when I deploy it to production and run it from SSMS it gives me that error. 
I install those drivers on production, but it still gives me that error.